# BsMultiSelect and jQuery Validation compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, bsmultiselect

I have a website that's using [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for form validation and [BsMultiSelect](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-4-Multi-Select-BsMultiSelect.html) as a nicer multiselect field. The problem is BsMultiSelect replaces the `select` element with its own `div` and I don't know how to validate that.

I have this HTML code:

```
<form method="post" id="server-form" class="form-responsive m-auto">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="categories">
            Categories
            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </label>
        <select name="categories[]" id="categories" class="form-control"  multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

And this Javascript:

```
$(function(){
        $('#categories').bsMultiSelect();

        $('#server-form').validate({
            rules:{
                'categories[]':{
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 3
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Which is working without BsMultiSelect but not with it. Is there a way to make these plugins compatible with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) BsMultiSelect have its own github project: https://github.com/DashboardCode/BsMultiSelect .

2) One of options to add custom validation to it is to get BsMultiSelect validationApi - its emulates HTMLEntity validationApi.

```
var bsMultiSelect = $('#myselect').BsMultiSelect(); 
bsMultiSelect.validationApi.setCustomValidity("error message") // or set to "" to remove the message
```

Then you will need to integrate it with jquery validation: listen its events and add or remove the message.